# complex sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

my series and sequence knowledge has gone a little rusty so I was wondering if you could help me on the right path here.

The assignment is to calculate the sum of the series $(\frac{1}{8})^n  e^{j(n{\pi})/8}$ as $n$ goes toward infinity.

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: it seems to be a geometric series, is it $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{8^n}\cdot \exp\left( i\cdot \frac{n\cdot \pi}{8}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{8^n}e^{n\pi i/8}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{\pi i/8}}8\right)^n=\ldots$$

Remember: if $\,q\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;|q|<1\;$ , then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty aq^n=\frac a{1-q}$$

Comment: Is this a certain rule or statement that can be referenced? the latter one.

Comment: Of course. You can easily prove it using basic rules of geometric series and limits.